# PHP SSH Warning: stream_get_contents(): Failure 'would block' (-9)"

Tags: php, ssh

I got a Warning from my code

> Warning: stream_get_contents(): Failure 'would block' (-9) in /var/www/html/public_html/site.php on line 51

It is thrown only at this command:

> service apache2 reload

My code is:

```
public function exec( $cmd, &$output = '' ) {
        $connection = ssh2_connect( '*********', 22 );
        ssh2_auth_password( $connection, '********', '******+*' );

        $stream      = ssh2_exec( $connection, $cmd );
        $errorStream = ssh2_fetch_stream( $stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR );
        stream_set_blocking( $errorStream, TRUE );
        stream_set_blocking( $stream, TRUE );

        var_dump( $cmd );
        echo '<br>';

        $output = stream_get_contents( $stream );
        $error  = stream_get_contents( $errorStream );

        if ( strlen( $error ) > 0 ) {
            var_dump( $error );
        }

        fclose( $errorStream );
        fclose( $stream );
    }
```

The code is starting at line 39, the warning is on the line with the

> $output = stream_get_contents( $stream );

Any solution against the warning ?

**EDIT**

The function is in a class that is a part of a webinterface to manage the vhosts

Some Informations about the Server:

#### Apache

```
root@development:/# apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Server built:   Aug 28 2015 16:28:08
```

#### PHP

```
root@development:/# php -v
PHP 5.6.13-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Sep  7 2015 13:38:37)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

#### OS

```
root@development:/# uname -a
Linux development 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u3 (2015-08-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@development:/# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.2 (jessie)
Release:        8.2
Codename:       jessie
```

Comment: So you get the error when you reload the Apache configuration while some pages are being rendered?

Comment: It is before the rendering, other commands that are invoked before or after are working.

Comment: What does it mean "it is before rendering"? Do you mean you connect to SSH before the PHP code renders the page? So in other words: Do you get the error when you reload the Apache configuration while some PHP scripts/pages are executing?

Comment: Its only a php Script not rly a complete website. After this only comes a table

Comment: So the script is not related to the Apache at all?

Comment: A bit cause its a component for a small webinterface to configure vhosts

Comment: You maybe you can edit this into your question with few more details. Otherwise the question is hardly answerable.